# Simple docker-compose.yml no mantiene la app corriendo (se ejecuta y cierra)

Tags: php7, docker, docker-compose, yml

estoy haciendo pruebas con los ficheros `docker-compose.yml` , con instrucciones muy simples pero no termina de funcionar.

Os expongo mi prueba:

1. He creado un fichero `./testphp/index.php` y el fichero `index.php` contiene:

```
<?php

echo "IM PHP TEST..!";

?>
```

2. Desde mi directorio actual (`./`) me he creado un `docker-compose.yml` y le he puesto esta configuración:

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  php:
    image: php:7.3.33-cli-alpine3.14
    ports:
      - 1234:80 #apache
    volumes:
      - ./testphp/index.php:/app
```

Mi directorio actual (`.`), donde esta mi **docker-compose.yml** es:

```
.
└── testphp
    └── index.php
```

Segun entiendo, deberia de crearse un contenedor, que al acceder a mi localhost:1234 deberia de mostrar el texto que esta en el **index.php** de prueba.

Entonces ejecuto:

```
docker-compose up
```

Output:

```
Starting docker_test_php_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_test_php_1
php_1  | Interactive shell
php_1  | 
php_1  | php > docker_test_php_1 exited with code 0
```

No hay ningun contenedor corriendo:

```
~/Documentos/docker_test  docker ps                     
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Intento arrancar el contenedor creado.. y se cierra tras mostrar esto:

```
 ~/Documentos/docker_test  docker start -i  d1bd4b55aeb4 
Interactive shell

php > %
```

La imagen es una de php 7.3 sin mayor configuracion, he leido que puede pasar porque este mal bindeado el `volume` pero no veo que sea eso.

**Importante: ** No estoy usando, ni quiero usar `Dockerfile` para esta prueba.

Answer (score 2):

El contenedor lo creas para que ejecute un script que finaliza rapido y al finalizar este proceso el contenedor se para, con esto evita que se queden procesos en plan zombies o cosas por el estilo.

Para que un contenedor se quede en ejecucion permanentemente necesita un proceso que no finalice, por ejemplo: si creas un contenedor con un Apache, este tiene un proceso de apache que esta siempre en ejecucion, pero esto no pasa con PHP porque entiendo que esta pensado para ajecutar scripts y listo.

Para que tu contenedor se quede siempre en ejecucion, puedes añadir a tu docker-compose.yml la siguiente linea:

```
command: tail -f /dev/null
```

Este comando coge el fin del archivo /dev/null, el cual no tiene nada y con la opcion -f, se queda en ejecucion mirando el archivo todo el rato y va mostrando en pantalla las actualizaciones que van pasando en el archivo, al no tener nada el archivo /dev/null el proceso se queda siempre activo y no molesta mostrando cosas en la pantalla.

Comment: Sólo para añadir que `/dev/null` es un archivo como todo en *nix (procesos, archivos, etc.), pero se puede asimilar a `un hoyo negro`. No va a crecer en tamaño, no se va a consumir tu disco.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque tu código termina, al ejecutar tu "echo" ya no tiene más que hacer y termina, es el comportamiento esperado de un back-end en PHP, ejecuta el script y acaba. Lo que intentas hacer es visualizar y quedarse ahí como un frond-end estático. Revisa los losgs de tu contenedor con "docker logs " y verás que sí ejecutó tu echo y terminó.

Comment: Hola tu respuesta no es clara o pudiese ser mejorada. Por favor edita tu respuesta y añade mayor información para que esta publicación pueda ser útil para la comunidad y puedas recibir medallas, puntos, entre otras valoraciones.

Answer (score 0):

No está bien la manera de puesto volumen.

Vez de apuntar el archivo a un directorio

```
volumes:
      - ./testphp/index.php:/app
```

Usas este. Un directorio a un directorio

```
volumes:
      - ./testphp:/app
```